# DtKsh related with Bad Interpreter issue

Tags: shell, ksh, desktop-environment

I want to create a `Hello World` exmaplo in CDE, as KSH scripting like [this](http://www2.phys.canterbury.ac.nz/dept/docs/manuals/unix/DEC_4.0e_Docs/HTML/DTKSH/DOCU_007.HTM#HEADING26) and [this](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/appa_04.htm)

I've started on this at my job; there are computers with AIX, so I tested the previous examples successfully. Then I want to try them in my computer with Debian, but I'm having this error:

```
-bash: ./hello: /usr/dt/bin/dtksh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Actually this is my code:

```
#!/usr/dt/bin/dtksh
XtInitialize TOPLEVEL dttest1 Dtksh $0
XtSetValues $TOPLEVEL title:"dttest1"
XtCreateManagedWidget BBOARD bboard XmBulletinBoard $TOPLEVEL \
   resizePolicy:RESIZE_NONE height:150 width:250\
   background:SkyBlue
XtCreateManagedWidget BUTTON pushbutton XmPushButton $BBOARD \
   background:goldenrod \
   foreground:MidnightBlue \
   labelString:"Push Here" \
   height:30 width:100 x:75 y:60 shadowThickness:3
XtRealizeWidget $TOPLEVEL
XtMainLoop
```

**In addition:**

This is what I do when I create and to execute the script:

1. vim hello.ksh
2. After created my file I use `chmod +x namescript`
3. then `./hello.ksh`

**Consulted**

I've search few information about this:
[reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-and-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)
[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735541/shell-script-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-when-using-pwd)
[reference3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097528/bin-shm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)
[reference4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304999/not-able-to-execute-a-sh-file-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter)

I used the `dos2unix -k -o filename` conversor

also the `:set fileformat=unix` in vim.

How could solve this? I'll appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Do you _have_ `/usr/dt/bin/dtksh` on your machine?

Comment: Mmm no, there's no any clue of `/dt` path... Is it any way to get it? I have already `KSH` installed.

Comment: It doesn't look simple; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368229/how-to-install-cde-on-debian may help but that's 3 years old...

Comment: Mmm I'll trying with a `SparkyLinux` Distro, I'm going to be updating the topic periodically. Thank you @StephenHarris